# SQL Server Security: prevent authorized Active Directory users from reading data

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, windows-authentication

I have a Web intranet application that uses integrated AD authentication.  This app is connected to a SQL database which is accessed via the user token.  The problem is that any user that has authorization to access the app, can also query the server directly, bypassing the app.  The only way I can think of securing this server is by using a firewall that would block all hosts other than the app.
Can anyone recommend a technique that would only let the app connect/authenticate to the DB, without using a FW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is an option for your environment and if application and sql server are on the same machine you can try disabling all external connections to sql server. This way, only app would be able to connect but not external users.

Answer (score 1):

See the first answer in this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606338/sql-server-windows-authentication-security) post.
As the author says there isn't any total solution, you'll always have a compromise.

In my opinion user impersonation is the way to go.

Comment: Looks like the aforementioned FW is the best option so far.  As I do not want to change the Auth schema and don't feel like tweaking the perms on the SQL resources.   This is probably the best practice since you want to restrict access at the furthest (from SQL server) entry point.  In my case, it's the OS, being this box is on the same subnet.  If it was on a separate sub/vlan or behind a network FW, then the most remote equipment would be used to restrict access, just the same.

Comment: Yes, you should be fine by doing so. Especially now that the app is already designed and implemented.